# android pager tab strip in bottom taking entire fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, pager

i want to have a view 
where in first there would be adview over the fragment and in last with botton android pagertabstrip will be present, but somehow pagertabstip taking full page.
my code is below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/adview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_below="@+id/adview"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/adview"
    android:background="@color/black" >
</com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How i make this work, with tabstrip bottom and pager view top,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `layout_gravity="bottom"`, because `ViewPager` extends `FrameLayout`, so it's the same parameters that `FrameLayout` uses. `android:layout_alignParentBottom` is for `RelativeLayout`

**edit:**

Re-read your question and your XML. I thought you were using the standard [PagerTabStrip from the support library](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html), but this is what you want:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/adview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_below="@+id/adview"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/black" >
</com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Remove the `android:layout_below="@+id/adview"` from the tab. It's making the tab start immediately after the adview.

Comment: hi it is in relative layout, cause i wanted to adview float on fragments

Comment: I read wrong your question, I edited my answer. Should be correct now.

Comment: thankx a lot, its worked like a magic, and seems i didnt understand how relative view work :(

Comment: it works!! But, There is a way to set 'underline' selector as 'upperline'?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/adview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.9"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:background="@color/black" >
</com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: its worked also, but adview not float on viewpager. thanks to help me

Answer (score 0):

Use - `layout_gravity="bottom"`

Why? Because, `FrameLayout` is extended by `ViewPager`

Comment: hi it is in relative layout, cause i wanted to adview float on fragments,